# Accessing database with pgAdmin in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In my current non-Kubernetes environment, if I need to access the Postgres database, I just setup an SSH tunnel with:

`ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 user@domain.com`

I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar in a test Kubernetes cluster I am setting up in EKS, that doesn't involve a great security risk. For example, creating a path in the ingress control to the databases port is a *terrible* idea.

The cluster would be setup where Postgres is in a pod, but all of the data is on persistent volume claim so that the data persists when the pod is destroyed.

How would one use pgAdmin to access the database in this kind of setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kubectl` command can [forward TCP ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward) into a POD via the kube-api

```
kubectl port-forward {postgres-pod-ID} 5432:5432
```

If you are not using a cluster-admin user, the user will need to be bound to a role that allows it to `create` `pods/portforward` in the pods namespace.

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pg-portforward
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/portforward"]
    verbs: ["create"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar kind of setup. My postgreSQL database is deployed in a pod in kubernetes cluster running in AWS cloud. Following are the steps that I performed to access this remote database from pgAdmin running in my local machine (Followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viuggqNLBcE)).

1 -> Modify the Service type of db from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` as shown below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db

spec:
  selector:
    app: db
  ports:
    - name: dbport
      port: 5432
      nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

2-> Add new rule to security group of any node(EC2 Instance) of your Kubernetes cluster as shown below.

[image]

3-> Connect to this remote database using the public IPv4 address of the node(EC2 Instance).

**HostAddress:** IPv4 address of the node ec2 instance.

**Port:** 31000